# Do Chronicle products support 32-bits JVM and Java 8

Tags: java, chronicle, chronicle-map

I would like to start using Chronicle products with our system, but due to C++ libraries we need to use 32 bit JVM. Do chronicle products support 32-bits JVM.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we support java 8 and have run with 32bit JVM's in the past ( although are not actively testing against them ). If you are interested in using chronicle with C++ we have a C++ version. Please email sales@chronicle.software if you would like more information on this.

Answer (score 1):

We test our software on 32 bit ARM and x64. If you have any issues with x86 let us know.